# tabs from another html page inside a tab of my html page -web application user interface

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

Am creating a web application having 4 tabs... Each tab contains a sidemenu (jQuery) and the remaining part is divided into 2, topdiv and bottom div (table with 2 colums.. col1=sidemenu, col2=topdiv+bottomdiv) ... I use

```
    $("#topdiv").load("contents/abc.html #xyz")
```

To load contents of div xyz to topdiv, which(xyz) is in another page `abc.html`  when I click a particular link in the sidemenu... But sometimes when `#xyz` will again have 4 or 5 tabs ,those tabs are not available as tabs in `#topdiv`... instead they appear as just list.. am using `$("#___").tabs()` for creating tabs...can anyone help me? I cannot add images here since am not having enough reputations in stack overflow. if some one provides ur email address I can attach images of my current status of page and those of which I need to design... here is part of ma code.

```
 ============================================================================
  

      home.jsp
        ======================================================================
                <div id="mainmenu" class="tabs">
                    <ul>
                        <li ><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#tab3">tab3</a></li>
                     </ul>
        
        <div id="tab1">
        </div>
        
        <div id="tab2">
        
                     <div id="topdiv">
                      </div>
                    <div id="bottomdiv">
                       </div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="tab3">
        </div>
        
        </div> 
        
        
        ===========================================================================  
        abc.html
        ============================================================================
        <div id="xyz">
             <div id="innertabs" class="tabs">  
                <ul>
                     <li ><a href="#innertab1">inner tab1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#innertab2">inner tab2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#innertab3">inner tab3</a></li>
                
            </ul>  
                       <div id="innertab1">inner tab 1 contents</div>
                       <div id="innertab2">inner tab 2 contents</div>
                       <div id="innertab3">inner tab 3 contents</div>
                    
               </div>
        
        </div>
        
        
        ===========================================================================================
        main.js//javascript---jquery-ajax connected
        ===========================================================================================
        
        $(".tabs").tabs();
        $("#topdiv").load("contents/abc.html #xyz");
        enter code here
    
    
    
        
              ========================================================================================
```

pls note that div '#mainmenu' is appearing in tab format... but "#innertabs" also having class "tabs" is not appearing in tab format.. instead they appear in #topdiv as lists and contents below it
===========================================================================================

Comment: are you using jquerytabs? $( "#tabs" ).tabs();

Comment: yes .. am using $("#___").tabs()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atlast after a lot of researchs and experiments, i hav found a solution to this... actually i hav to use unique div ids for tabs instead of class = "tabs"... then the tab statement will change to $("#innertabs").tabs(); but to make sure that $().tabs() is invoked only after loading the contents, put that statement in a callback function of $().load()... so my actual problem was $("#innertabs").tabs() is invoked even before it is loaded into #topdiv from the page abc.html..hence they can be displayed only as lists as there is no div with id=innertabs at the time of $().tabs() is invoked. . now it is avoided and the working code is

```
$("topdiv").load("contents/abc.html #xyz",function(){$("#innertabs").tabs();});
```

so only after loading the div into topdiv, corresponding tabs are generated and thus it will be displayed as tabs itself

so i think its good to use a callback function all the time when u need this stuff to be done without any errors... 
also if anyone came to know about the disadvantages of this method pls do post here.. it wll be helpfull for me as a fresher
looking forward to a career in software development...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you using jquery ui tabs.
If so after loading other page content, apply again tabs function on main div

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs();
```

Actually you should apply `.tabs()` after ajax content is loaded. Not before that. I am not sure if applying `.tabs()` twice may damage it.

**Update**:
Here is fiddle for you [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aFdeb/) . then your code will be

```
 $("#mainmenu").tabs();
 $("#topdiv").load("contents/abc.html #xyz");
 $("#innertabs").tabs();
```

Comment: am adding class=".tabs" to all those div i need to be as tabs... then i add $(".tabs").tabs() in jquery.. is that a correct way... am not getting the desired result... after loading am getting ma main tab which is inside ma page in tab format but the loaded content frm other page does not appear as tabs

Comment: No its not correct way, you wrap that in a div and give that div an Id, for example "my_div" and apply like $( "#my_tabs" ).tabs(); http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: can you please post a simple working example of what i hav asked... i mean can u just create a page containing 2 or 3 tabs and inside any of dat tab load a div containing 2 or 3 tabs from another page ... if u send me ur email id i can just mail u d images of my current page status and my target design

Comment: Can you post you whole code? or just paste if on http://jsfiddle.net/ and save and send me link

Comment: its not working for me.. but i hav found something strange..i hav already mentioned about ma 4 tabs in main page having 4 different sidemenus...i wrote those 4 side menus in 4 different javascript functions and loaded all of them using window.onload along with this $(#mainmenu).tabs() and $("#innertabs").tabs(); the strange thing is if i add an alert("hai") in all the side menu functions i am getting the inner tabs right... but if i just avoid those alert()s am getting innertabs as list.. so i think ma actual problem s related to multiple onload & trigger time.. any idea???

Comment: i also tried to make all the sidemenu functions into 1 single function... here also the inner tab works only if an alert() statement is in b/w the $().load() statement and $().tabs() statement... so i think d problem s related to not getting enough time to load div from another page before the $().tab() is invoked... i don't want dat alert in b/w... instead is der any option to wait or add a delay untill div frm other page loads completely and after complete load invoke $().tab() ???? is it a right approach???

Comment: dude i think i hav found ma answer... using a callback function in $().load() and writing the code for $().tab() inside that callback function... it works great... it ensures that $().tabs() is invoked only after loading the contents completely... so my javascript code will change like dis...$("#topdiv").load("contents/abc.html #xyz",function(){$("#innertabs").tabs();});... i think you also become pleased with this finding... thanks for all your support dude.. also notify me if this method hav any disadvantages if you ever came to know